# Getting IPV4 address from ipconfig

Tags: powershell

I want to fetch only the line which contains `IPv4 Address` when we type `ipconfig` using power shell is there any way to do it quickly?

Comment: There might be more than one matching line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only output the Ipv4-Adress line, you can use `Where-Object` alias `?`

Example output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ipconfig | ? { $_ -match 'Ipv4' }
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.140
```

If you want to create a PowerShell Object out of it use `Select-Object` alias `select`:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ipconfig | ? { $_ -match 'Ipv4.*: ((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})' }| select @{n="IPv4";e={$Matches[1]}}

IPv4      
----      
10.0.0.140
```

If you want to have a PS Object though I would, as the other answer says, use `Get-NetIPAddress`

Comment: Only one -match neccessary `ipconfig | ? { $_ -match 'Ipv4.*: ((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})' }|select @{n="IPv4";e={$Matches[1]}}`

Comment: @LotPings Thank you! I updated my way of parsing to your way of parsing

Answer (score 2):

Use the Get-NetIPAddress cmdlet.

To apply a filter for IPv4 only, you can pipe the Get-NetIPAddress output to a Where-Object.

```
(Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4'}).IPAddress
```

Check out the documentation for other parameters and information:

[Get-NetIPAddress documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps)

Comment: At least from PSv3+ the script block in the [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-3.0) isn't neccessary.

Comment: Never knew that, good one!

Comment: Well, if you process a text file there is no property to act a comparison on, or if you do calculations the script block is still needed. Should have mentioned these restrictions.